# How to read TCP packets more quick manner?

Tags: c

Here I sent TCP packets into loopback interface. Simultaneously I tried to capture those packets from that interface using pcap library. But that capturing took some time and causes to slow down whole process. So I need to find out way to read TCP packets quickly.(code is in c language)

```
while (1) {
    u_int max_len = 1514 - sizeof (packet_hdr);
    if (max_len < (tot_len - data_send))len = max_len;
    else len = tot_len - data_send;

    packet = finalize(packet_hdr, arr, len, tmp_len, src_port, src_ip, dst_port, dsts_ip, eth_src, eth_dst);  //initialize TCP header fields.

    u_char *buff_cpy = (u_char*) malloc(sizeof (packet));
    memcpy(buff_cpy, (const u_char*) &packet, sizeof (packet));

    int send = pcap_sendpacket(conn_handler, buff_cpy, sizeof (packet_hdr) + packet.len);  //send TCP packets into loopback interface.

    free(buff_cpy);
    packet1 = pcap_next(conn_handler, &packet_header);  //capture sent packets into loopback interface
    printf("capture: %d\n", packet_header.caplen);

    if (send == -1) printf("PACKET NOT SEND");
    data_send += packet.len;
    if (data_send == tot_len) break;
}
```

here is part of my code and used pcap_next() to capture packet.But it took some time.So I need to speedup that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read the ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for an understanding of what is considered a good question here.  Good questions generally contain code, and not a complete upload of your entire project...but a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you've built which focuses directly on the specific point you want to ask about.  But also, optimization questions may not be appropriate here...see ["Can I post questions about optimizing code"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261841/211160).

Answer (score 1):

Try RAW sockets and `recvfrom()`. It should be pretty fast. Example:

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (fd != -1)
{
    char buf[2345];
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);
        int len = recvfrom(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addrlen);
        printf("len = %d\n", len);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

Example code receives all incoming TCP packets with IP headers. 
You can bind it to loopback-interface, if needed.
You must implement other filtering by yourself.

For binding to loopback-interface:

```
struct ifreq ifr;

memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "lo", sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &ifr, sizeof(ifr));
```

Comment: Thanks for advise. I will try this method.